# Setting Screen session name in the middle of the session

Tags: screen, customization, session

[Screen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen) allows to set a custom session name during a session startup using a `-S` switch

```
screen -S your_session_name
```

How to set a custom session name after a screen session has been created ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> `(Ctrl a :)`

leads to a prompt in the screen terminal where one can type

```
sessionname your_custom_session_name
```

This sets the custom name to the current screen session. Now typing `screen -list` shows the screen with the custom session name.